# Blueimp file upload progress bar restart on each file if image resized

Tags: php, jquery, blueimp

I'm using bluimp file upload: all it's work fine but if I add this line of code in the function the progress bar restart from zero on each file...I wont a progress all bar! If I remove that code (for the image resizing ) the progress bar works correctly.

```
disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
    .test(window.navigator && navigator.userAgent),
imageMaxWidth: 2126,
imageMaxHeight: 2126,
loadImageMaxFileSize: 20000000,
```

Here is my full function:

```
                        $(function () {
                            var count = 0;
                            var qt = 1;
                            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                            dropZone: '',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                                .test(window.navigator && navigator.userAgent),
                            imageMaxWidth: 2126,
                            imageMaxHeight: 2126,
                            loadImageMaxFileSize: 20000000,
                            formData: [{ name: 'custom_dir', value: <?php echo $_SESSION['folder']; ?>+'/singleprint/' }],
                            done: function (e, data) {
                                    c = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
                                    $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                                        $('<div class="sp-item"><div class="sp-image-preview"><a data-lightbox="uploadedfiles" data-title="'+file.name+'" href="uploads/<?php echo $_SESSION['folder']; ?>/singleprint/'+file.name+'"><img alt="'+file.name+'" id="original-image'+c+'" style="cursor: pointer;" src="uploads/<?php echo $_SESSION['folder']; ?>/singleprint/thumbnail/'+file.name+'"></a></div><div class="sp-image-options"><span class="image-name">'+file.name+'</span><br />Quantit&agrave; <select class="singleImageQt" name="qt-'+qt+'" onchange="updateQt();"><?php for($o=1;$o<11;$o++){echo '<option value="'.$o.'">'.$o.'</option>';}?></select><input type="hidden" name="filename-'+qt+'" value="'+file.name+'"></div></div>').appendTo("#image-grid");
                                        count=count + 120;
                                        qt = qt + 1;
                                    });
                                },
                            progressall: function (e, data) {
                                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                                $("#percentage").html(progress);
                                if(progress != 0){
                                    $('#progress .uploadbar').css(
                                            'height',
                                            '10px'
                                        );
                                    $('#container-box').css(
                                            'opacity',
                                            '0.05'
                                        );  
                                    $('#progress').css(
                                            'opacity',
                                            '1'
                                        );                                          
                                }
                                $('#progress .uploadbar').css(
                                        'width',
                                        progress + '%'
                                    );
                                if(progress == 100){
                                    $("#sp-quantity").html("<p>"+qt+"</p>");
                                    $("#general-qt").html("<span>"+qt+"</span>");
                                    $('#nimmagini').val(qt);                            
                                    $('#progress .uploadbar').css(
                                            'height',
                                            '0px'
                                    );
                                    $('#image-grid').css({
                                            "opacity":"1","z-index":"1"
                                    }); 
                                    $('#image-grid-container').css(
                                        'height',
                                        count+'px'
                                    );
                                    $('#progress').css(
                                            'opacity',
                                            '0'
                                    );
                                    $('#container-box').css(
                                            'opacity',
                                            '0'
                                        );                                          
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
```